# How to modify this regular expression to extract strings with this pattern?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract the string that are between the quotation mark `"` and `.pdf`. For example, `"../matlab/license_admin.pdf" abc "vfv"` -> `../matlab/license_admin.pdf` and `"license_admin.pdf" xyz'` -> `license_admin.pdf`. I try the following code:

```
import re

base = '"../matlab/license_admin.pdf" abc "vfv"'
base1 = '"license_admin.pdf" xyz'

result = re.findall(r'\b(\S+\.pdf)\b', base)
result1 = re.findall(r'\b(\S+\.pdf)\b', base1) 

print(result)
print(result1)
```

but it only works with the my second example. The code remove `../` in my first one:

[image]

Could you please help me modify the regular expression `\b(\S+\.pdf)\b` to achieve my goal? Thank you so much!

Comment: If it is between `"` and `.pdf`, why aren't you using `re.findall(r'"(.*?\.pdf)', base)` (or - better -- with `re.search` since you expect a single match only)?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, I have no experience with regular expression :( I just copied the code from somewhere on the Internet 9 months ago.

Comment: In your own words, what does `\S` mean in this context?

Comment: @Crush_on_You Your expression does not match all of the first example because `\b` matches a position only, if there is a "word" character on one side and a non-word character on the other. `"` and `.` are both non-word characters, so the regex engine skips ahead in trying to match `\b` until it is between `/` and `m`. Don't use `\b` unless you expect to match around "words", i.e sequences of [a-zA-Z0-9_]. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
import re

bases = ['"../matlab/license_admin.pdf" abc "vfv"', '"license_admin.pdf" xyz']
for base in bases:
    m = re.search(r'"(.*?\.pdf)', base)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vCHRmk)

Output:

```
../matlab/license_admin.pdf
license_admin.pdf
```

The `"(.*?\.pdf)` pattern matches `"`, then captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars but line break chars, as few as possible, and then `.pdf`. With `re.search`, you get the first match, and `m.group(1)` acccesses the Group 1 value.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEwfpO/2).